# What is the syntax for adding a shape to the canvas in react native + skia

Tags: react-native, canvas, drawing, skia

I keep getting errors about there being no existence of .drawRect or .drawRectagle. I cant find the syntax for these in the docs. The issue might also be in how I have referenced the canvas aswell. I just want to add a rectangle when I click on the button.
The eventuality of this as you can see is me drawing a circle on the user's position. Im just trying to get there using this library because Ive been told it is more optimized. Im probably missing something here but for the life of me I cant find and example projects or api refrences to this

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import {
  Canvas,
  Image,
  useCanvasRef,
  Circle,
  Skia,
  Paint,
  
} from "@shopify/react-native-skia";

import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {
  GestureDetector,
  Gesture,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const DrawingApp = () => {
  const canvasRef = useCanvasRef();
  const [isDrawingRectangle, setIsDrawingRectangle] = useState(false);

  const drawRectangle = () => {
    setIsDrawingRectangle(true);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDrawingRectangle) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      console.log("Drawing rectangle");
      if (canvas) {
        const paint = Skia.Paint();
        paint.setColor(Skia.Color("blue"));
        // canvas.drawRect({ x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100 }, paint);
        canvas.drawRectangle({ x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100 }, paint);
      }
      setIsDrawingRectangle(false); // Reset the flag to stop drawing after one click
    }
  }, [isDrawingRectangle]);

  const [points, setPoints] = useState([{ x: 0, y: 0 }]);

  const panGesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onBegin((e) => {
      const startingPoint = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
      setPoints([startingPoint]);
    })
    .onUpdate((e) => {
      const newPointToAdd = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
      setPoints([...points, newPointToAdd]);
      // rerenderCanvas();
      // Create picture

    })
    .onEnd((e) => {
      const endPoint = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
      setPoints([...points, endPoint]);
    });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <View className="w-[100%] h-[100%] bg-white">
        <GestureDetector gesture={panGesture}>
          <View>
            <Button title="CLICK MEEEEEEEEEEr" onPress={drawRectangle}>

            </Button>
          <Canvas ref={canvasRef} class="bg-black">

          </Canvas>
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default DrawingApp;

const arePositionsTooClose = (position1, position2) => {
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(position2.x - position1.x, 2) +
      Math.pow(position2.y - position1.y, 2)
  );
  return distance < 0;
};
```